# How to get upload progress for multiple files? (React + React-dropzone + Axios + onUploadProgress)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-dropzone

I'm trying to create a multi-upload drag and drop with React and [react-dropzone](https://react-dropzone.js.org/). Everything works great, except that I can't seem to get the progress information for the uploads even though I'm using `onUploadProgress` with Axios.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles) => {
  acceptedFiles.forEach((file) => {
    let response = axios.put(`/api/files-endpoint`, file, {
      onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
        console.log(`progress ${progressEvent}`);
      },
    });
  });

  setFiles(acceptedFiles);
}, []);
```

Am I doing something wrong? In the browser I have tried with both firefox and chrome, even throtthling the connection to slow 3g to see if it will trigger the condition on those circunstances but still no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any logs at all?

Comment: What browser are you using? There's a note in the [source code](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v0.x/lib/adapters/xhr.js#L185) warning that _"Not all browsers support upload events"_

Comment: I don't see anythings in the logs. And I tested both firefox and chrome. @Phil

Comment: What is `file` in the code above? Is it a `FormData` instance? If not, I'm struggling to picture how anything actually gets uploaded. If you change both server and client sides to use `POST` instead of `PUT`, do you see any change? Basically, rule out any browser weirdness by using the simplest / oldest method of uploading files, ie `POST multipart/form-data`

Comment: does the following sandbox work for you? https://playcode.io/974737

Answer (score 0):

The [upload example](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v1.x/examples/upload/index.html#L25) in the axios repo uses a FormData object, try adapting your code to use FormData too

```
const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles) => {
  acceptedFiles.forEach((file) => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', file);
    let response = axios.put(`/api/files-endpoint`, data, {
      onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
        console.log(`progress ${progressEvent}`);
      },
    });
  });

  setFiles(acceptedFiles);
}, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
    const { loaded, total } = progressEvent;
    let precentage = Math.floor((loaded * 100) / total);
    console.log(precentage);
    if (precentage < 100) {
      console.log(precentage);
    }
  }
```

destructure `loaded` and `total` variables and calculate the percentage from it.